# Twitter Bootstrap Style = "width: 45%;"

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In using the Progress Bar from Twitter Bootstrap, I would like to set a changing variable being sent to the style width parameter:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 20%;"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to change the width after obtaining a percentage number from a database file.

For example, if the number retrieved from the database is 80 I would then incorporate the 80 into the percentage portion of the style:

style="width: 80%;"

I have tried using variables in Javascript within HTML and I am not getting very far.

Thanks for your help,

Tommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this answer helped, I like to explain both the JavaScript and jQuery methods of performing the task you want.

jQuery method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var progWidth = /* The way you'd access the database file to obtain the percent. */
    $('.progress-striped > .bar').width(progWidth + "%");
});
```

Pure JavaScript method:

```
document.onload = function() {
    var progWidth = /* The way you'd access the datbase file to obtain the percent. */
    $('.progress-striped > .bar').width(progWidth + "%");
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the 2nd sollution is pure javascript since  $('.progress-striped > .bar') is a jquery method

Answer (score 1):

Put the percentage in a var and use it in javascript or jQuery. I'll use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theWidth = // Wherever you get the var;
    $(".progress-striped > .bar").width(theWidth + "%");
});
```

To elaborate on the "your var" part, we need to know how you are getting the database information.

Comment: Ftr, this way `theWidth` will be interpreted as `px` and not as a percentage.